# Polymorphism - Call Base class function

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Is it possible to call base class function without modifying both base and derived classes?

```
class Employee {
    public String getName() {
        return "Employee";
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return 5000;
    }
}

class Manager extends Employee {
    public int getBonus() {
        return 1000;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
        return 6000;
    }
}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Employee em = new Manager();
        System.out.println(em.getName());
        // System.out.println(em.getBonus());
        System.out.println(((Manager) em).getBonus());
        System.out.println(em.getSalary());
    }
}
```

Output:
     Employee
     1000
     6000

How shall I call the Employee's getSalary() method on `em` object?

Comment: Seems like duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784542/force-invocation-of-base-class-method.

Comment: @Jiri, thanks. Actually I searched but don't know how I missed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't. You could add a method like this to `Manager` if you wanted:

```
public int getEmployeeSalary()
{
    return super.getSalary();
}
```

Comment: *I* don't; the original poster wanted to get the value returned by that method. Perhaps `Employee` and `Manager` are just example classes here, and we're really speaking in more general terms about calling overridden methods.

Comment: In more general terms the OP wants to break polymorphism, which is just *wrong*. In this case the obvious missing piece is the many-many association between manager and employee.

Comment: I'm pretty sure these are just examples, but rather than being "the salary his employees make" it could also be "the salary he'd get if he wasn't a manager", and in that case in theory this is a legitimate thing to want to do. But the decision is, and should be, up to the implementor of `Manager`, not to some random client, which is why there's no way to do it without that implementor's cooperation.

Comment: So finally it is not possible to do it without changing the Manager class!! But as pointed out, I would be breaking polymorphism. I asked out of curiosity.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Employee object instead:

```
Employee em = new Employee();
```

Comment: I want to use the existing `em` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the superclass's method from within the subclass.

```
class Manager extends Employee {
    public int getBonus() {
    return 1000;
    }

    public int getSalary() {
    return super.getSalary();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read my question. It's without changing Employee or Manager code.