# Java force Object::toString

Tags: java

This is mentioned in one of the comments on this question:
[Force invocation of base class method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784542/force-invocation-of-base-class-method)
Wondering if there as a way to force the Object.toString instead of MyClass.toString. Just want it for debugging logs (want to see if a library is creating multiple objects or re-using the same one). e.g. Something like

```
myObject.Object::toString()
```

Can this be done easily? We are using java8

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it can't be done easily. But there's no need. If you want the hex number the default `toString()` method prints, call [`System.identityHashCode()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode-java.lang.Object-).

Answer (score 2):

No, In java it's impossible as far as I know.
However, there are some workarounds:

Workaround 1:

```
class MyObject {
   public String toString() {
       return super.toString() + <whatever_of_my_object>;
   }
}
```

Workaround 2:

```
class MyObject {

      public String toIdentityString() { // this is your custom function you can call it foo 
           return super.toString();
      }
}
```

And then use toIdentityString to print id of the object